# How to execute SSIS ETL package using Python

Tags: python, ssis, etl

I have a SSIS package which i am currently running using Visual Studio. I want to know is there any mechanism in python by which i can execute those SSIS packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`DTExec`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/packages/dtexec-utility?view=sql-server-2017) to run the SSIS package. You basically launch an external process to run the package. You can execute packages that are stored on the SQL Server as well as packages that are on he filesystem. It's a pretty flexible tool with command line arguments to support many scenarios.

Comment: Thanks , But i wanted to implement it using python

Comment: @mao I know, but Python doesn't have any packages that do this. Your best option is running `DTexec` from your Python code or running a stored procedure from Python which executes your package on the server.

Comment: @MarcelN. not sure if it is the best option, I disagree, I have added an answer of my own.

Answer (score 2):

You can execute a Transact-SQL script that call for the execution of the dtsx package.

This has an advantage over other answers, because you do not need to have acces to the DTExec (that requires access to the machine where the SSIS Service is running) and works for other programming languages (most if not all of them allow executing TSQL).

The only requirements would be:

- Be able to connect to the SQL Server Database service within python (pyodbc or similar)
- Configure the Integration Services Catalog in the SQL Server Database service

Microsoft quickstart: [SSIS with TSQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/ssis-quickstart-run-tsql-vscode?view=sql-server-ver15)

Stored procedure documentation: [catalog.create_execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/system-stored-procedures/catalog-create-execution-ssisdb-database?view=sql-server-ver15)

Code example, extracted from the quickstart:

```sql
Declare @execution_id bigint
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[create_execution] @package_name=N'Package.dtsx',
    @execution_id=@execution_id OUTPUT,
    @folder_name=N'Deployed Projects',
      @project_name=N'Integration Services Project1',
    @use32bitruntime=False,
      @reference_id=Null
Select @execution_id
DECLARE @var0 smallint = 1
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[set_execution_parameter_value] @execution_id,
    @object_type=50,
      @parameter_name=N'LOGGING_LEVEL',
      @parameter_value=@var0
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[start_execution] @execution_id
GO
```

Comment: I believe this is the best approach as well

Answer (score 0):

You can use batch file as a tool to execute SSIS packages. First, you need to setup batch file and then just use the following code in python:

```
 import subprocess
 subprocess.call([r'full_path_to_batch_file_directory/batch_file.bat'])
```

Answer (score -2):

You can do this with an 'Execute Process Task'.  Use the following entries

- Executable: pythonw.exe
- Arguments: this will be your script file

Still working on cleaning up the error processing so that it can report errors better, but it is processing the script correctly.

Comment: The question is the opposite of your answer. Your answer is `SSIS -> Python` and the question is `Python -> SSIS`